# Restriction of functional in the calculus of variantions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any constraint on the functional $F$ for an Euler-Lagrange problem? For instance, if we take

$$f(y,y')=y'+y$$
and let $F$ be the integral of $f$ on a certain interval.

Then Euler-Lagrange equation becomes
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=1\ne0=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$$

which is obviously impossible. What is the prohibiting this particular $F$ to be a functional? Does the functional have to satisfy certain constraints (say, being non-negative)?

Comment: I think it might have to do with the functional having no extremums (maxs. or mins.)

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. That's a good point. Thanks for pointing it out. It makes sense since Euler-Lagrange is finding the stationary point, but I am not sure how to quantify the condition of having an extremum, given it is a functional, not a simple function.

Comment: You want to minimize $J[y]=\int(y'+y)\, \mathrm dx$. If you introduce the typical perturbation $J[y+\varepsilon\eta]$, you'll see the functional is linear in $\varepsilon$, which means it won't present absolute maxs nor mins far sny $y$.